# Method not returning int

Tags: java

I don't understand why this method compiles correctly.

```
public int doIt() throws Exception{

      //code that does not include a return int statement

     throw new Exception("something");
   }
```

We declared a return type of int so why am I not recieving a warning like: "This method must return a result of type int"?

Comment: Because throwing an exception makes the method end it's execution, so you don't need to return something anymore

Comment: If you try to catch the exception, it won't compile.

Comment: An exception is a valid alternative for a return value.

Answer (score 6):

Every control flow of a method needs to terminate in *either* a return of the appropriate type, or in a thrown exception.  See the language specification:

> #### [8.4.7. Method Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)
>
> If a method is declared to have a return type, then every return
>   statement (§14.17) in its body must have an Expression, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time
>   error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).
>
> > *In other words, a method with a return type must return only by using a return statement that provides a value return; it is not
> >     allowed to
> >     "drop off the end of its body".*
> >
> > > *Note that it is possible for a method to have a declared return type and yet contain no return statements. Here is one example:*
> > >
> > > ```
> > > class DizzyDean {
> > >     int pitch() { throw new RuntimeException("90 mph?!"); }
> > > }
> > > ```

A method that throws an exception never returns, and the compiler's static code analysis can determine this.  That is, the compiler can examine the program control flow, and determine that *every* execution path through the method body *either* returns a value of the appropriate type, or throws an exception.  It's important to note that this is based only on program structure, and not on value analysis.  E.g., the compiler will complain about a case like:

```
int returns42() {
  if ( 2 > 1 ) {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

Even though `2 > 1` will always be true, when the compiler looks at the structure

```
int fnName() {
  if ( condition ) { 
    return …;
  }
}
```

is essentially says "what happens if `condition` is false?  Then this doesn't return a value!"  (This is a contrived case, and some compilers might be able to handle the constant case of `2 > 1`, though I don't know what restrictions there are on Java compilers.)

Comment: Good answer,+1.It would be helpful for future users if you provide more info like *compilers static code analysis*

Comment: I have already upvoted and can not do more.YOur answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

Because your method never returns.

The compiler is able to tell that you always exit via non-local transfer (i.e. you throw an exception 100% of the time), so it has no need to warn you about the return value, because no code will ever receive it.

Looking at it in reverse:

If a caller were to have:

```
 int x = o.doIt ();
```

… there is no case in which `x` could receive a non-integer. (There is also no case in which `x` could receive an integer)

Answer (score 1):

Definition: An exception is an event, which occurs during the execution of a program, that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions.
So

this statement `throw new Exception("something");`

is terminating the execution that's why you are not getting that warning.

[See this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)